# How to create a treeview with Angular

Tags: css, angular, treeview, angular14

I'm writing a project with angular 14 and I need to create [such a treeview,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCQtn.png) but I don't know how to do it. I want help from those who have knowledge about this subject.

Comment: Most component libraries will have a tree component if you're happy to use those e.g. https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/tree or https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer, yes I am using it, but I need to give a performance close to pixel perfect in this project, so I asked the question.